# Convert PDF file to XLSX using liberoffice command line

Tags: node.js, excel, ubuntu, xlsx, libreoffice-calc

I'm using the below command which is intended to convert PDF files to XLSX format

`soffice --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to xlsx:"Calc MS Excel 2007 XML" excel.pdf --outdir test.xlsx`

But I'm getting an error message which states **Application Error**. I need to know what is wrong with my command and solution to convert PDF files to XLSX.

Comment: I have no knowledge about `soffice` usage but is it normal that your `--outdir` option seems to specifiy a output file and not a output directory ?